# AS3: How can I check a variable with an if statement?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So this bit of code seems like it should run smoothly to me but i can't seem to be able to use an if statement to check the score then make the button appear. Any suggestions?

```
//Score variable
var score = 0;

//Multiplier variable
var multiplier = 1;

//Point Scorer
function PointScore() {
score = score + multiplier;
}

//update score function
function updateScore() {
txtPlayerScore.text = "Smash Points: " + score;
}

//Score Text
txtPlayerScore.text = "Smash Points: " + score;

//Make Power Up button invis
btnPowerUp.visible = false;

//If the score is 50 the button is now visible
if (score == 50){
btnPowerUp.visible = true;
}

//Power Up button
btnPowerUp.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, UpClicked);

function UpClicked (e:MouseEvent){
multiplier = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code you posted, the if check is pointless because it happens immediately after you set the score to 0. You want to check the score every time it changes, for example put it inside your `PointScore()` function. Also, you probably want that to be `if(score >= 50)` instead of `== 50`, otherwise if the score passes by 50 it won't trigger the condition.

```
function PointScore() {
    score = score + multiplier;
    checkScore();
}

function checkScore(){
    if(score >= 50){
        btnPowerUp.visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: works perfectly. just used == 50 instead to make it do what i need. Thanks :)